# Eliminar seleccion del listbox ya abierto

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo un problema, tengo una APP con varias pestañas, y un listboxm al cambiar de pestaña me gustaria que el Listbox, desmarque la opcion selecionada, pero solo funciona con la ultima pestaña abierta, os paso unas imagenes y un ejemplo.

[image: PAGINA PRINCIPAL]

[image: PRIMERA PESTAÑA ABIERTA Y MARCADO UN TAG DEL LISTBOX]

[image: ULTIMA PESTAÑA ABIERTA, DONDE SI SE ELIMINA EL TAG SELECIONADO]

**El codigo principal es este,os paso con comentarios:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ScrollableNotebook import *
from extracion import Extracion
import json
import os

idOpenTab = 0

# Lista de clientes 
list_client = [
    "AFB",
    "ASISA"
]

#Carga mi usuario y la ruta de los ficheros
mypath = os.path.expanduser("~/")
path_modulo = mypath+"Compliance/file/desviaciones_{}.json"

class Aplicacion():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Example")
        
        '''
        crear la pestañas desde otro fichero .py
        '''
        self.notebook = ScrollableNotebook(
            self.root, 
            wheelscroll=True, 
            tabmenu=True,
            application=self,
        )
        
        '''Creamos la primera pestaña'''

        frame1 = Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(frame1, text="WorkSpace")
        self.notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.notebook.bind_all("<<NotebookTabChanged>>",lambda e:self.alCambiar_Pestaña(e))
        text = Text(frame1)
        text.pack()
        Label(frame1, text="Pantalla PRINCIPAL").pack()
        
        ''' Crear boton para crear pestañas de EXTRACION'''
        Button(frame1,
               text="Issues EXTRACIONES",
               command=self.abrir_issuesExtracion,
               ).pack()

        ''' Crear boton para crear pestañas de DESVIACION'''

        Button(frame1,
               text="Issues DESVIACIONES",
               command=self.abrir_issuesDesviacion,
               ).pack()

    ''' FUNCION PARA ABRIR EXTRACION '''

    def abrir_issuesExtracion(self):
        print("aqui extracion")
        self.extracion = Extracion(self.notebook, application=self)
        self.notebook.add(self.extracion, text="Issues EXTRACIONES")

    ''' FUNCION PARA ABRIR DESVIACION '''

    def abrir_issuesDesviacion(self):
        print("aqui desviacion")
        self.desviacion = Desviacion(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.desviacion, text="Issues DESVIACIONES")

    ''' FUNCION DONDE QUIERO QUE ME DESMARQUE EL TAG SELECIONADO DEL LIST BOX '''

    def alCambiar_Pestaña(self, event):
        #global idOpenTab
        #idOpenTab = event.widget.index('current')
        #tab = event.widget.tab(idOpenTab)['text']
        #print("ID : {}, TEXT : {}".format(idOpenTab,tab))
        self.desviacion.DESVfr1_listbox.selection_clear(0,END)

    def cerrar_ventana(self):
        self.notebook.forget(idOpenTab)
        self.notebook.notebookContent.forget(idOpenTab)

    def mainloop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
class Desviacion(ttk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.widgets()
    
    def widgets(self):

        ''' BUTTON PARA CERRAR PESTAÑA '''
        self.btn_nav = Button(
            self,
            text="CERRAR PESTAÑA",
            background="#39A2DB",
            border=0,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            relief='flat',
            command=app.cerrar_ventana
        )
        self.btn_nav.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
        
        ''' OPTION MENU PARA ELEGIR EL CLIENTE'''
        
        self.clientesVar = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.clientesVar.set('CLIENTES')
        self.DESVfr1_optMn = tk.OptionMenu(
            self, 
            self.clientesVar, 
            *list_client, 
            command=self.cargar_Modulos,
        )
        self.DESVfr1_optMn.config(
            background = "#5F939A",
            foreground = "#F2EDD7",
            font=('Source Sans Pro',15,font.BOLD),
            activebackground="#3A6351",
            activeforeground="#F6D167",
            relief="groove",
            borderwidth=2,
            width=20
        )
        self.DESVfr1_optMn["menu"].config(
            background='#3A6351',
            selectcolor='red',
            activebackground='#5F939A',
            foreground="#F2EDD7",
            font=('Consolas', 13, font.BOLD),
        )
        self.DESVfr1_optMn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='new', columnspan=2)
        
        self.DESVlist_yScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.DESVlist_xScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.DESVfr1_listbox = tk.Listbox(
            self,
            xscrollcommand=self.DESVlist_xScroll.set, 
            yscrollcommand=self.DESVlist_yScroll.set,
            foreground='blue',
            selectbackground='#297F87',
            selectforeground='#F6D167',
            disabledforeground='black',
            exportselection=False,
            highlightbackground='gray88',
            highlightthickness=2,
            highlightcolor='#297F87',
            height=20,
            width=50
        )
        self.DESVfr1_listbox.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5,15), padx=(5,15), sticky='nsew')
        self.DESVlist_yScroll.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5,15), sticky='nse', columnspan=2)
        self.DESVlist_xScroll.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, sticky='sew', columnspan=2)
        self.DESVlist_xScroll['command'] = self.DESVfr1_listbox.xview
        self.DESVlist_yScroll['command'] = self.DESVfr1_listbox.yview

    ''' FUNCION QUE CARGA DESDE UN JSON, LOS MODULOS E INFORMACION DEL CLIENTE SELECIONADO'''
    def cargar_Modulos(self, clt_modulo=None, *args):
        if clt_modulo is not None:
            customer = clt_modulo
        ## --- LIMPIAR -----------------------------
        
        self.DESVfr1_listbox.delete(0,END)
        
        with open(path_modulo.format(customer)) as g:
            data = json.load(g)
            listModulo = []
            for md in data:
                listModulo.append(md['modulo'])

        listModulo.sort()

        self.DESVfr1_listbox.insert(END,*listModulo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Aplicacion()
    app.mainloop()
```

Os paso ademas el fichero .py, que es de donde se crea las pestañas, este no tiene nada comentado porque no necesita ser revisado.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright (c) Muhammet Emin TURGUT 2020
# For license see LICENSE
from posixpath import commonpath
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import font
import os
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from threading import Thread
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
release = True
path = os.path.expanduser("~/")
path_icon = path+"Compliance/image/"
count = 0
class ScrollableNotebook(ttk.Frame):
    _initialized = False
    def __init__(self,parent,wheelscroll=False,tabmenu=False, application=None,*args,**kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        if not self._initialized:
            self._initialize()
            self._inititialized = True
        kwargs["style"] = "ScrollableNotebook"
        self._active = None
        self.xLocation = 0
        self._application = application
        self.WorkSpac_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path_icon+r"workspace.png").resize((20, 20)))
        self.novo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path_icon+r"novo.png").resize((25, 25)))
        self.notebookContent = ttk.Notebook(self,**kwargs)
        self.notebookContent.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.notebookTab = ttk.Notebook(self,**kwargs)
        self.notebookTab.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>",lambda e:self._tabChanger(e))
        if wheelscroll==True: 
            self.notebookTab.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._wheelscroll)
            self.notebookTab.bind("<Button-4>", self._wheelscroll)
            self.notebookTab.bind("<Button-5>", self._wheelscroll)
        slideFrame = ttk.Frame(self)
        slideFrame.place(relx=1.0, x=0, y=0, anchor=NE)
        self.menuSpace=30
        if tabmenu==True:
            self.menuSpace=50
            self.bottomTab = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                text="  \u2630  ", 
                                background='#DF2E2E',
                                foreground='#F6D167',
                                width=5, 
                                anchor="center"
                                )
            self.bottomTab.bind("<1>",self._bottomMenu)
            self.bottomTab.pack(side=RIGHT, ipady=12)
        self.bottomTab_novo = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                image=self.novo,
                                text="Abrir",
                                width=5,
                                padding=(5,0),
                                background="#082032",
                                foreground="white",
                                )
        self.bottomTab_novo.bind("<1>",self._bottomMenu_novo)
        self.bottomTab_novo.pack(side=LEFT, ipady=8)

        self.leftArrow = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                text=" \u276E ",
                                foreground="#297F87",
                                )
        self.leftArrow.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start())
        self.leftArrow.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._release_callback)
        self.leftArrow.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.rightArrow = ttk.Label(slideFrame, 
                                text=" \u276F ",
                                foreground="#297F87",
                                )
        #rightArrow.bind("<1>",self._rightSlide)
        self.rightArrow.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start())
        self.rightArrow.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self._release_callback)
        self.rightArrow.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.notebookContent.bind("<Configure>", self._resetSlide)
        self.notebookTab.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
        self.notebookTab.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)
        self.notebookContent.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_tab_close_press, True)
        self.notebookContent.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_tab_close_release)
    
    def _release_callback(self, e):
        global release
        release = True
        self.rightArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')
        self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')
    
    def on_tab_close_press(self, event):
        name = self.identify(event.x, event.y)  
        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index
    
    def on_tab_close_release(self, event):
        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return None
        name =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if name == "tab_btn_close":
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            if index != 0:
                if self._active == index:
                    self.forget(index)
                    self.notebookContent.forget(index)
                    self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")
        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None
    
    def _initialize(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.images = (
        tk.PhotoImage("img1", data='''
            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
        ''' ),
            tk.PhotoImage("img3", data="""
            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
        """)
        )
        self.style.element_create("tab_btn_close", "image", "img1",
                            #("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img2"), 
                            ("active", "!disabled", "img3"), border=15, sticky=''
        )
        self.style.layout("ScrollableNotebook", [("ScrollableNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        self.style.layout("ScrollableNotebook.Tab", [
            ("ScrollableNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe", 
                "children": [
                    ("ScrollableNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top", 
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("ScrollableNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top", 
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("ScrollableNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": 'nsew'}),
                                    ("ScrollableNotebook.tab_btn_close", {"side": "left", "sticky": 'nsew'}),
                                ]
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ])
        self.style.configure('ScrollableNotebook',
                            background='#082032',
        )
        self.style.configure("ScrollableNotebook.Tab",
            background='#FDD2BF',
            foreground='#012443',
            padding=[2, 2],
            anchor="center",
            justify="center",
            font=('Sans-Serif', 12, font.BOLD)
        )         
        self.style.map('ScrollableNotebook.Tab', background = [("selected", "#B61919"),
                                                    ("active", "#FF6B6B")],
                                        foreground = [("selected", "#ffffff"),
                                                    ("active", "#012443")]
                                                    )
    
    def _wheelscroll(self, event):
        # if event.delta > 0:
        #     Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start()
        # else:
        #     Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
        global count
        # # respond to Linux or Windows wheel event
        # if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
        #     count -= 1
        #     Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start()
        #     #self._rightSlide()
        # if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
        #     count += 1
        #     Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
        #     #self._leftSlide()
        print(count)

    def _bottomMenu(self,event):
        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=13)
        tabListMenu = Menu(self, tearoff = 0)
        for tab in self.notebookTab.tabs():
            tabListMenu.add_command(label=self.notebookTab.tab(tab, option="text"),
                                    command= lambda temp=tab: self.select(temp),
                                    background='#ccffff', 
                                    foreground='blue',
                                    font=self.text_font,
                                    activebackground='#004c99',
                                    activeforeground='white')
        tabListMenu.entryconfig('WorkSpace  ', 
                                accelerator="ALT+W",
                                image=self.WorkSpac_icon, 
                                compound='left', 
                                label='  WorkSpace')
        try: 
            tabListMenu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        except:
            self.bottomTab.configure(background='#DF2E2E',
                                foreground='#F6D167')

    def _bottomMenu_novo(self,event):
        self.text_font = tkFont.Font(family='Consolas', size=13)
        self.tabListMenu = Menu(self, tearoff = 0)
        #for tab in self.notebookTab.tabs():
        self.tabListMenu.add_command(
            label="  Extraciones", 
            #accelerator='Ctrl+F',
            command=self._abrir_issuesEXT,
            background='#ccffff', foreground='black',
            activebackground='#004c99',activeforeground='white',
            font=self.text_font,
        )
        self.tabListMenu.add_command(
            label="  Desviaciones", 
            #accelerator='Ctrl+F',
            command=self._abrir_issuesDESV,
            background='#ccffff', foreground='black',
            activebackground='#004c99',activeforeground='white',
            font=self.text_font,
        )
        self.tabListMenu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    
    def _abrir_issuesEXT(self):
        self._application.abrir_issuesExtracion()
        Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
        self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')

    def _abrir_issuesDESV(self):
        self._application.abrir_issuesDesviacion()
        Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
        self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')

    def _tabChanger(self,event):
        if event.state == 0:
            self._resetSlide(event=None)
        try:
            self.notebookContent.select(self.notebookTab.index("current"))
        except: pass

    def _rightSlide(self):
        global release
        release = False
        self.rightArrow.configure(foreground='#DF2E2E')
        while not release:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if self.notebookTab.winfo_width()>self.notebookContent.winfo_width()-self.menuSpace:
                if (self.notebookContent.winfo_width()-(self.notebookTab.winfo_width()+self.notebookTab.winfo_x()))<=self.menuSpace+5:
                    self.xLocation-=20
                    self.notebookTab.place(x=self.xLocation,y=0)
                else:
                    self._release_callback(e=None)
    
    def _leftSlide(self):
        global release
        release = False
        self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#DF2E2E')
        while not release:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            if not self.notebookTab.winfo_x()== 0:
                self.xLocation+=20
                self.notebookTab.place(x=self.xLocation,y=0)
            else:
                    self._release_callback(e=None)

    def _resetSlide(self, event):
        self.notebookTab.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.xLocation = 0

    def add(self,frame,**kwargs):
        named = kwargs['text']
        if len(self.notebookTab.winfo_children())!=0:
            self.notebookContent.add(frame, text=named,state="hidden")
        else:
            self.notebookContent.add(frame, text=named,state="hidden")
        self.notebookTab.add(ttk.Frame(self.notebookTab),**kwargs)
        id_tab = self.tabs()[-1]
        self.notebookTab.select(id_tab)

    def forget(self,tab_id):
        #self.notebookContent.forget(self.__ContentTabID(tab_id))
        self.notebookTab.forget(tab_id)

    def hide(self,tab_id):
        #self.notebookContent.hide(self.__ContentTabID(tab_id))
        self.notebookTab.hide(tab_id)

    def identify(self,x, y):
        return self.notebookTab.identify(x,y)

    def index(self,tab_id):
        return self.notebookTab.index(tab_id)
        #return self.notebookTab.index(self.notebookTab.select('current'))

    def __ContentTabID(self,tab_id):
        return self.notebookContent.tabs()[self.notebookTab.tabs().index(tab_id)]

    def insert(self,pos,frame, **kwargs):
        #self.notebookContent.insert(pos,frame, **kwargs)
        self.notebookTab.insert(pos,frame,**kwargs)

    def select(self,tab_id):
        self.notebookTab.select(tab_id)
        if tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame':
            self._resetSlide(event=None)
            self._release_callback(e=None)
        elif tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame2' or tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame3' or tab_id == '.!scrollablenotebook.!notebook2.!frame4':
            Thread(target=self._leftSlide, daemon=True).start()
            self.rightArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')
        else:
            Thread(target=self._rightSlide, daemon=True).start()
            self.leftArrow.configure(foreground='#297F87')

    def tab(self,tab_id, option=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs_Content = kwargs.copy()
        kwargs_Content["text"] = "" # important
        #self.notebookContent.tab(self.__ContentTabID(tab_id), option=None, **kwargs_Content)
        return self.notebookTab.tab(tab_id, option=None, **kwargs)

    def tabs(self):
        #return self.notebookContent.tabs()
        return self.notebookTab.tabs()

    def enable_traversal(self):
        self.notebookContent.enable_traversal()
        self.notebookTab.enable_traversal()
```

Ademas os paso la informacion de los ficheros Json, que en mi caso van en la ruta :

```
mypath = os.path.expanduser("~/")
path_modulo = mypath+"Compliance/file/desviaciones_{}.json"
```

los ficheros se llaman :

**desviaciones_AFB.json**

```
    [
  {
    "modulo": "Identify and Authenticate Users/PermitRootLogin Restriction",
    "clave": "PERMITROOTLOGIN",
    "descripcion": "SSH Config File: /etc/ssh/sshd_config; Invalid setting (value:yes) in parameter 'PermitRootLogin': must be set to 'no'.",
    "comprobacion": "",
    "copia": "",
    "editar": "",
    "refrescar": "",
    "evidencia": "",
    "SO": "Linux"
  },
  {
    "modulo": "Identify and Authenticate Users/Public Key Authentication",
    "clave": "PUBLICKEY",
    "descripcion": "SSH authorized_keys file: $authorized_keys; Invalid public host key length: 1024   Key type: ssh-rsa.",
    "comprobacion": "authorized_keys=\"\"\n\nls -la $authorized_keys\n\n## Comprobar, el tipo de cuenta para el owner o el tipo de cuenta de los usuarios del grupo.",
    "copia": "",
    "editar": "",
    "refrescar": "",
    "evidencia": "",
    "SO": "Linux"
  },
  {
    "modulo": "Password Requirements/Acceptance of the null password with nullok parameter",
    "clave": "NULLOK",
    "descripcion": "PAM service: /etc/pam.d/system-auth\nPAM service: /etc/pam.d/password-auth\n\nuse pam_unix.so auth module with \"nullok\" parameter. This parameter is forbidden as it allows acceptance of the null password.",
    "comprobacion": "",
    "copia": "",
    "editar": "",
    "refrescar": "",
    "evidencia": "",
    "SO": "Linux"
  }
]
```

**desviaciones_ASISA.json**

```
[
{
    "modulo": "E.1.5.22.4 Network Settings",
    "clave": "SENDMAIL",
    "descripcion": "Entry in /etc/rc.tcpip must be removed or disabled. : service sendmail",
    "comprobacion": "grep -i sendmail /etc/rc.tcpip|grep -v ^#",
    "copia": null,
    "editar": "chrctcp -d sendmail",
    "refrescar": null,
    "evidencia": "clear\ndate\nhostname\ngrep -i sendmail /etc/rc.tcpip|grep -v ^#",
    "SO": "Aix"
},
{
    "modulo": "Network Settings/NFS root restrictions",
    "clave": "NFS",
    "descripcion": "File /etc/exports has invalid line: XXXX",
    "comprobacion": null,
    "copia": null,
    "editar": null,
    "refrescar": null,
    "evidencia": null,
    "SO": "Aix"
},
{
    "modulo": "Identify and Authenticate Users/PermitRootLogin Restriction",
    "clave": "PERMITROOTLOGIN",
    "descripcion": "SSH Config File: /etc/ssh/sshd_config; Invalid setting (value:yes) in parameter 'PermitRootLogin': must be set to 'no'.",
    "comprobacion": "",
    "copia": "",
    "editar": "",
    "refrescar": "",
    "evidencia": "",
    "SO": "Linux"
}
```

]

---

En conclusion que al cambiar de pestañas y tener un tag del listbox marcado no me lo deseleciona.

Gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido marcada automáticamente por el sistema como muy extensa. No requiere ninguna acción por tu parte, pero es importante mantener las preguntas y la definición del problema lo más concreto posible para evitar ese tipo de publicaciones demasiado extensas. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero lo que comprendo es retirar la selección de un `tk.Listbox,` por lo cual por un momento pensaba que era eliminar un item de un `tk.Listbox`. Si es así, puede establecer un evento o `bind` al `tk.Listbox` que le permita desenfocar un item o por medio de un control como un botón, por lo cual la centrándome en el problema, mi solución sería la siguiente:

```
def QuitarSeleccion(event=None):
    DESVfr1_listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
```

> Utilizando una función retira la selección del Listbox independiente del control utilizado

**Usando un evento o bind:**

```
listboxEjemplo.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: listboxEjemplo.selection_clear(0, END))
```

**Usando un evento o bind en el control de pestañas:**

Usando un evento al hacer clic en las pestañas, retirará la selección del `tk.Listbox` con base en la llamada a la función `QuitarSeleccion()` anteriormente:

```
self.notebook.bind('<Button-1>', QuitarSeleccion)
```

**Ejemplo en situación real:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('335x303')
root.geometry('+560+250')
root.title('Ejemplo quitar selección')
root.maxsize(335, 303)
root.minsize(335, 303)

labelTextInfo = tk.Label(root, text="Ejemplo quitar selección de un item:", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8))
labelTextInfo.place(x=6, y=8)

listboxEjemplo=tk.Listbox(root, font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), borderwidth=2, selectmode='none', activestyle='none', height=13, takefocus=False, highlightthickness=0, exportselection=False)
listboxEjemplo.place(x=9, y=29, width=316)

scrollbarlistboxEjemplo = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scrollbarlistboxEjemplo.config(command=listboxEjemplo.yview)
scrollbarlistboxEjemplo.place(x=306, y=31, height=182)

listboxEjemplo.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbarlistboxEjemplo.set) 

for ItemAleatorio in range(15):
    listboxEjemplo.insert(tk.END, ItemAleatorio)

def HabilitarQuitarSeleccion(event=None):
    if len(listboxEjemplo.curselection())!=0:
        btnOkRemoveSelectedItem.config(state='normal', font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8))


def QuitarSeleccion(event=None):
    listboxEjemplo.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
    btnOkRemoveSelectedItem.config(state='disabled', font=("MS Sans Serif", 8))

def cerrarVentana(event=None):
    root.destroy()


listboxEjemplo.bind('<Return>', cerrarVentana)
listboxEjemplo.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', HabilitarQuitarSeleccion)       


btnOkRemoveSelectedItem = tk.Button(root, text='Quitar selección', font=("MS Sans Serif", 8), takefocus=False, width=13, command=QuitarSeleccion, state='disabled')
btnOkRemoveSelectedItem.place(x=158,y=268, height=22)

btnCancelar = tk.Button(root, text='Cancelar', font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), takefocus=False, width=10, command=cerrarVentana)
btnCancelar.place(x=255,y=268, height=22)  

root.mainloop()
```

Nota: Tenga en cuenta que este es un ejemplo y la variable o nombre del control es `listboxEjemplo`.

Comment: Hola, he probado tu respuesta pero no encaja a lo que busco, ya que no me quita la seleccion de un elemento del listbox, cuando tengo varias pestañas abiertas, no se si probaste mi codigo,puede crear varias pestañas y me gustaria que al cambiar de pestaña si existe un elemento selecionado, se desmarque .. pero no funciona ,  he probado el evento FocusOut, pero no desmarca de los list box que esten creado.. no se si me explico.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, aunque he actualizado la respuesta, el control de pestañas en lo que entiendo en su código es `self.notebook`, si es así puede revisar la actualización de la respuesta por lo cual, usando eventos en el control de pestañas que permiten de forma global realizar determinadas operaciones como deseleccionar un listbox o cualquier otra devolución de una llamada de una función por medio de un bind.

Comment: #John, sigue sin funcionar, he puesto una funcion llamada por medio de un bind, donde quita la selecion del Listbox, y si funciona, pero funciona con la ultima pestaña creada, te paso un ejemplo de los print que hecho para que veas,

Comment: Nombre del list :  **.!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion.!labelframe.!listbox**
Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  .!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion.!labelframe.!listbox
Nombre del list :                                                                                              ** .!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion2.!labelframe.!listbox **
Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  .!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion2.!labelframe.!listbox
Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  .!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion2.!labelframe.!listbox
Nombre del list :  **.!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion3.!labelframe.!listbox**

Comment: Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  .!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion3.!labelframe.!listbox
Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  **.!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion3.!labelframe.!listbox**
Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  **.!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion3.!labelframe.!listbox**
Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  .!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion3.!labelframe.!listbox
Nombre del List quitar Selecion :  **.!scrollablenotebook.!desviacion3.!labelframe.!listbox**

Comment: como veras el print que dice 'Nombre del list', es el print que se crear cuando creao una pestaña, y el print 'Nombre del List quitar Selecion :' , el el asociado a la funcion atravez de un bind 
``` 
def QuitarSeleccion(self, event=None):
        desviacion.DESVfr1_listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
        print("Nombre del List quitar Selecion : ", desviacion.DESVfr1_listbox) 
``` 
como el nombre del widget que devuelve es diferente, se supone que cada pestaña tiene su widget y se deberia de quitar la selecion al widget que esta actual., pero se quita en el ultimo creado